# EF Core 3.1 "does not match the corresponding member type"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, linq

Tengo un error al ejecutar esta consulta, en net core 3.1, pero en net core 2.1 corre sin problemas.

Al quitar "data" del select new, no muestra error, así que el error podría estar en "DateOfIssue", he revisado ese campo y ninguno es nulo.

Estoy utilizando net core 3.1.

Estoy consultando una lista de documentos, lo primero que hago es agruparlos en el tipo de documento y en cada tipo de documento los agrupo por día
Esto es lo que espero recibir.

**Tablas**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[documents](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date_of_issue] [date] NOT NULL   DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [document_type_id] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [total] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
) 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cat_document_types](
    [id] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [description] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [short] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [active] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
    [created_at] [date] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [updated_at] [date] NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()),

)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado**

```
[{
    id = 1,
    label = "Factura",
    total = 20, 
    data :[{day : 1 , total : 10 },{ day : 2 , total : 10}]
}]
```

**Consulta**

```
 var query = (from pa in _context.Documents
             group pa by new { pa.DocumentTypeId, pa.DocumentType.Description } into grp

             select
             new
             {
                 id = grp.Key.DocumentTypeId,
                 label = grp.Key.Description,
                 total = grp.Sum(x => x.Total),
                 data = (from pa in grp
                         group pa by new { pa.DateOfIssue.Day } into grp2

                         select new
                         {
                             day = grp2.Key.Day,
                             total = grp2.Sum(x => x.Total)
                         }).OrderBy(x => x.day)

             }).ToList();
```

**Error**

```
System.ArgumentException:  Argument type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType93`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable`1[<>f__AnonymousType93`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]' (Parameter 'arguments[3]')
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateNewArgs(ConstructorInfo constructor, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments, ReadOnlyCollection`1& members)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(ConstructorInfo constructor, IEnumerable`1 arguments, IEnumerable`1 members)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Update(IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitNew(NewExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.NewExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at FacturadorSunatPro.API.Services.DashboardService.Report(DashboardDto dashboardDto) in C:\Users\MIGUEL\source\repos\FacturadorSunatProd.API\FacturadorSunatProd.API\Services\DashboardService.cs:line 27
   at FacturadorSunatPro.API.Controllers.DashboardController.Data(DashboardDto dashboardDto) in C:\Users\MIGUEL\source\repos\FacturadorSunatProd.API\FacturadorSunatProd.API\Controllers\DashboardController.cs:line 48
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Hola, porque no dices que pretendes lograr con la consulta y alomejor se te pueda ayudar con una consulta alternativa a la tuya

Comment: @Japv Hola , gracias por tu respuesta , lo agregue a la pregunta

Comment: Porque no cambias `group pa by new { pa.DateOfIssue.Day } into grp2` por `group pa by pa.DateOfIssue.Day into grp2`? Probablemente el tipo anomino este causando ese error.

Comment: Revisando el error que da y buscando encontré esto , donde dice que debes acceder al valor de la propiedad en este caso creo que sería `pa.DocumentTypeId.value`, en mi caso es difícil poder hacer pruebas a tu código, quizás si haces un réplica y los subes a tu repositorio seria más fácil poder ayudarte
 `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007746/linq-argument-types-do-not-match-error-what-does-it-mean-how-do-i-address-i/3008006`

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero, cree esta habitación para hablar de tu problema https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120307/japv

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero, hola resolviste?

Comment: @Einer lo intente , pero es lo mismo

Comment: @Daniel no puedo acceder a la propiedad "value"

Comment: @Japv aun no lo he podido resolver

Comment: @AntonioGuerrero, seria bueno que nos dieras la estructura de tus tablas para poder reproducir tu error, de otra forma estamos en el aire

Comment: @Japv hola , acabo de agregar esa información

Answer (score 0):

He modificado un poco tu query para lanzarla tipo lambda, no he podido probarla pero creo que te puede funcionar:

```
_context.Documents
.GroupBy(g => new { g.DocumentTypeId, g.DocumentType.Description })
.Select(g => new {
    id = g.Key.DocumentTypeId,
    label = g.Key.Description,
    total = g.Sum(x => x.Total),
    data = _context.Documents.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeId == g.Key.DocumentTypeId)
        .GroupBy(grp2 => new { day = grp2.DateOfIssue.Day })
        .Select(grp2 => new { 
            day = grp2.Key.day,
            total = grp2.Sum(x => x.Total)
        }).ToList().OrderBy(x => x.day).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Comment: hola , gracias por tu respuesta , pero en .Sum(x => x.Total) ,sale el error "bool" no contiene una definicion para "Total" ni un metodo de extensión accesible

Comment: Hola, he actualizado la respuesta, prueba de nuevo por fa

Comment: hola , me genera un error parecido respecto a los tipos = System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType93`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType93`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType93`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]] OrderBy[<>f__AnonymousType93`2,Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType93`2[System.Int32,System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]]],